# how to get xml header tag data in snowflake for a large xml , while using STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using this code to get large xml data in staging into snowflake,
for which I have to use STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE, other wise error occurs:

**Error parsing XML: document is too large, max size 16777216 bytes**

```
COPY INTO SAMPLE_DB.SAMPLE_SCH.T_TABLE (CATALOG_XML)
FROM @META_DB.CONFIG.STAGESNOWFLAKE/catalogmain.xml
FILE_FORMAT=(TYPE=XML STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE) 
ON_ERROR='CONTINUE';
```

ON THIS XML, **which is very large**

```
<catalog xmlns="http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/catalog/2006-10-31" catalog-id="catalog1">
    <product product-id="prod1">
     ..
     ..
     ..
    </product>
</catalog>
```

AND I GET THIS RESULT 
AS CATALOG_XML: (**not getting catalog tag data**)

```
<product product-id="prod1">
 ..
 ..
 ..
</product>
```

I need to get **catalog-id** from this xml, is there any way to get this ?

Answer (score 1):

With [`STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = FALSE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html#type-xml), the whole XML document will be read into a single value. Irrespective of being cast as a VARCHAR or [VARIANT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#variant) type, in a COPY INTO statement or in a [direct file query](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-transform.html), the **16 MiB size-limit** in Snowflake for those data types cannot be bypassed.

You can try splitting your XML file to manageable sized pieces, preserving the parent tags, and uploading smaller files carrying the same amount of data.

For example, the following javascript program in Node.js can break the files into fixed numbers of `product` elements per file, [while preserving the outer `catalog` element in each file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlsplit). This produces a directory of broken-down files, which can be loaded and queried without running into the 16 MiB limit.

```sh
~> mkdir /tmp/xsplt /tmp/split_files && cd /tmp/xsplt
~> npm init && npm install xmlsplit

~> cat > splitter.js << EOF
var xs = require('xmlsplit')
var fs = require('fs')

// Split into 500 product element data per document
var xmlsplit = new xs(batchSize=500)
var inputStream = fs.createReadStream("/tmp/large-input.xml")

var counter = 1;
inputStream.pipe(xs).on('data', function(data) {
    var xmlDocument = data.toString()
    fs.writeFile(
        `/tmp/split_files/output-part-${counter}.xml`,
        xmlDocument,
        (err) => { if (err) { console.log(err) } })
    counter += 1
})
EOF

~> node splitter.js

# Original input line count
~> wc -l /tmp/large-input.xml
500002
# Lines per split file
~> wc -l /tmp/split_files/output-part-1.xml
502
# No. of smaller files
~> ls /tmp/split_files/ | wc -l 
1000
```

Other alternatives could be to try a [CSV export of the data](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC2/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/catalogs/b2c_csv_file.html) instead of XML, or perform a local file format conversion before loading the data into Snowflake.

**P.s.** For help with loading and querying the split files, checkout the [earliest revision of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62038822/revisions).

Comment: Your solution is correct for normal small XMLs, but in my case I load a very large xml , for which I have to use STRIP_OUTER_ELEMENT = TRUE. Sorry I did not mention the xml as large in my original post. Have corrected the same, Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! However, I dont have an option to use scripting in the current design of things, and export to csv instead of xml also is not practical for me. Would need an approach that uses snowflake entirely.